# How to change the default route from component to another component after user login?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I created my default route to the dashboard component like this

`{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }`

And I need to change it to home component after login , so I need to know if it possible to handle this issue throw run time .

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After successful login use router to go to dashboard, for example: You are passing `this.user` to your authentication service which contains username and password. The authentication service provides you the result and if successful then redirect.

```
this.service.authenticate(this.user).subscribe(result => {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
}
```

You need to add logic to check if `result` is successful and then redirect it but handle the login errors if there is any. You need simple if/ else logic here.
You need to add `Router` to constructor and import it:
`protected router: Router`

Answer (score 0):

// In Login component you have to import Router

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

//Include Router in constructor

constructor(private router: Router, private FormBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

//after login api success you can directly use code like this


return this.Service.post(this.url + 'authentication/userLogin', this.user).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200)
    {
//You can give any component and file path in router.navigate
this.router.navigate(['/home/dashboard']);
}
```